# Integrated app pool and virtual directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, virtual-directory

I have MVC application that uses integrated app pool.

Under this MVC application, i have created a virtual directory that points to our file server location. This file server has some pdfs and custom images.

When we try to access the resources via virtual directory, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\nas2\CardDeck\web.config'.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: \\nas2\CardDeck\web.config    Line: 0 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

When I change the app pool to classic, i can access these resources just fine. What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App pool was running under "NetworkService" identity.

I have changed it to a user account that has admin permissions on the box.

The thing that i still need to figure out is, why these were working under classic app pool and network service as the identity?